# How can I set the dialog to an exact X and Y coordinate in the screen?

Tags: android, dialog

i'm trying to use a dialog like a spinner because it's more customizable visually. I want to place the dialog bottom of the view that invokes it. I've seen that the Gravity by default is CENTER. So I tried this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params.copyFrom(optionList.getWindow().getAttributes());
params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
params.x = this.getLeft();
params.y = this.getBottom();
optionList.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

But it is not working, the dialog always appear at the center of the screen like before.
Anyone knows if i'm mistaking something?